# ¿ Como aumentar el hueco entre los productos en WooCommerce?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, margin, padding

Quiero aumentar la separación entre los productos de una tienda, tanto por la parte superior como por los lados, pero no consigo hacerlo de forma uniforme.
teniendo en cuenta los clases que tienen los contenedores, estoy haciendo esto:

```
 .product-small{
            margin:10px;
    }
```

El problema es que esto mueve tambien las imagenes de los productos y deja 4 columnas en lugar de 5, lo cual puede ser porque este establecido un ancho por defecto en la plantilla de la página.

¿ Como separar los productos sin que afecte a las imágenes y se mantengan las 5 columnas de productos ?

Muestro las clases que tienen los productos y una imagen de lo que esta ocurriendo al tratar de añadir margin

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi es como se ven los productos antes de añadir el margin

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

////////////////////////////////////

Y esto es es lo que sucede

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Haz probado con padding en vez de margin, te recomiendo leer https://hackr.io/blog/margin-vs-padding

Comment: Si he probado pero eso estropea los productos, ya que como bien se explica en tu enlace, el margin es el espacio entre el objeto y el resto de objetos, cuando el padding es el espacio entre el contenido de un objeto y el borde de este mismo objeto. Dicho esto repito que padding en la clase `.product-small` desfigura los elementos. Gracias por dedicar tu tiempo